# Responding to user events in different Activities

Tags: android, httprequest, android-event

What's the best way for an Activity to respond to events from another Activity? For example, suppose I get to Activity B from Activity A. B has a button that does something (specifically, send some info via http request). Now when I go back to Activity A, I need something to detect that this button has been pressed to refresh some new data via another http call.

I could place the update code in `onResume` of Activity A but that would trigger even if the button was not pressed. If I need to do http requests, placing it in `onResume` would result in requests all the time not just when the button is pressed. Not very efficient.

Are callbacks the way to go or does something work better?

Comment: How about using onActivityResult()? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should help. You can return results from an activity by starting it with startActivityForResult(intent, resultId)

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html